# How to put a link inside every td of table that should be visible outside of table in html css

Tags: html, css

I have a table, I have a link on every `td` of the table. but I need to put those link in such a way it should look outside of the table. I have done that but in the first cell has been created I need to hide it. If I hide that `td` with CSS my link is also going to hide. Here is the HTML

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>
  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>link</span></td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>link</span></td>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>link</span></td>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are trying to put the link inside of table then how they can appear outside the table. Can you elaborate your requirement a little bit more

Comment: I want to put inside every td of the table but that should look like outside,I have already done but first td I need to hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved it with additional CSS hopefully it will work for you.

```css
td{
  position:relative;
}
  
span{
  position:absolute;
  left:-80px;
}

table.table.table-bordered {
    border-left-width: 0;
}

table.table td:first-child {
    border: none; 
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><span>link</span></td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>link</span></td>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>link</span></td>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's why we are here! :)

Comment: It's always better to increase specificity instead of using `!important` in order to override CSS rules. In this specific case, using `table.table td:first-child` will allow you to omit the `!important` and still have the same result.

Comment: @Connum Thanks for your advice. I also put the `width:0` which will remove extra pixel from the top-left and bottom-left of the table.

Comment: I am getting problem in case I add thead if I add <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>   before <tbody> , Actually that <th>Link</th> also I don't want to show in my table but it will be there in code

Comment: you have to target the First `<th>` with `table.table th:first-child {}` or something like that!

Comment: Thanks I updated it in plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1A5RmAzzJ0TllJ6x8YK4?p=preview

Comment: use this code: 
`table.table td:first-child {
    border: none; 
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
}` as I edited my previous code which may be un-noticed by you!